# LinkedIn Refresh Access Token OAuth 1.0\2.0

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Has any one tried to refresh the access token (without requiring user input).

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token

The documentation at the link above makes it seem like this is possible only for OAuth 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

you're right, the document at the link is just for OAuth 1.0. For OAuth 2.0, LinkedIn [Document](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) just says`Access tokens have a life span of 60 days. You should have a mechanism in your code to refresh the tokens before they expire in order to continue using the same access tokens.`
I haven't found any details about how to refresh token without user input in LinkedIn OAuth 2.0. Standard OAuth 2.0 should support this function.

And here's a talk about this in [LinkedIn Developers Forum](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-refresh-oauth2-token).

Comment: Thanks, I still haven't found any way to refresh the token. The only crazy approach  - store the user\password and communicate with linkedin throught web requests to get cookies that requierd for authorization. Have tested this with help of the Fiddler's Composer. some kind of _full trusted_ scenario.